# (node:31873) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Item is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Whenever I want to make a POST request using Postman I get this error: TypeError: Item is not a constructor. Any idea why? I have my code here:

```
const Item = require('../model/item.js');

const createItem = async(req,res) => {

    const category = await categoryService.findCategoryByName(req.body.category);
    const newItem = new Item({
        name: req.body.name,
        created: new Date(),
        category: [category],
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
    });

    try{
        await newItem.save();

        res.status(201).json(newItem);
    }catch(error){
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message});
    }
};
```

And item.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const categSchema = require("./category.js")

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    created: {type: Date, required: true, unique: true},
    category: [categSchema.categorySchema],
    quantity: {type: Number, required: true}
});

var itemData = mongoose.model("itemData", itemSchema);
module.exports.itemData = itemData;
module.exports.itemSchema = itemSchema;
```

Comment: Where/how is `Item` defined?

Comment: Can you include implementation of `Item` class? Or it's just some of the included classes from Postman?

Comment: I'm sorry i missed that, here, i edited

Comment: And what would be a possible solution to this? I mean it worked for a while and then stopped. I managed to put some Items in my database using this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing the full `exports` object, not just part of it. That object is not a constructor function (it's not a function at all).

Looking at your exports: According to the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) (I don't use Mongoose), `mongoose.model` returns a constructor function. So:

1. Export it using standard naming for constructor functions (`ItemData`, rather than `itemData`), and
2. Import it rather than the entire exports object

So for instance:

```
module.exports.ItemData = mongoose.model("itemData", itemSchema);
module.exports.itemSchema = itemSchema;
```

and to import it (by destructuring it from the exports object):

```
const { ItemData } = require("../model/item.js");
//    ^−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−− destructuring
```

Then, `new ItemData` should work.

Alternatively, import the whole thing (`const item = require(/*...*/);`) and then use `new item.ItemData`.